# I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

Keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to display a specific item form array list data displays fine in logcat but then after displaying throws exception at top please help is the code kind of new to android

```
public void loadData(){
        InputStream file = ourContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cashpot);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));       
        String line ="";
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                values.add(line);
              //  String[] strings = line.split(",");


                /*for(String s : strings) {
                    values.add(s);
                }*/

            }
            reader.close();
            //for(String s : values) Log.d("CSV Test", s);
            for(int i = 0; i < values.size();i++){
                String[] data = values.get(i).split(",");
                Log.d("Test String",data[2] );

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

Comment: When you get a runtime exception like this one, debug your code by stepping through it at runtime while checking your values. One/some of them will not have the expected values. Start by setting breakpoints.

Comment: the split might not returned an array of 3 elements ? meaning that data[2] doesn't exist. try printing data array before accessing any element in it.

Comment: Side note: You should call `reader.close()` in the `finally` block to ensure proper ressource closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your some lines do not have comma(,)(or 1 comma) and you are trying to split them by comma and storing it in to data array. and you are accessing data[2] location. which might not been created that's why you are getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be a 3rd element in your array ,that is created after the split on ",".
You can print value of data before accessing data[2](that might not exist).
Or you can Debug your program and proceed step by step and monitoring the value of each variable.